# Listview BaseAdapter Data not being shown

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview

I'm trying to populate a listview using a BaseAdapter, the problem I'm having is the textview which shows the data, refuses to actually draw the text.
I've called getText() on the textview, and it does show the correct information, however for some reason, it simply is not being rendered.

CustomAdapter:

```
public class CardListviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> numbers;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public CardListviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> numbers) {

    this.context = context;
    this.numbers = numbers;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numbers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return numbers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        Log.i("Inflating","Inflating Layout...");
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation,null);

    }
    holder.numbers = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.numbertitle);

    Log.e("Number",holder.numbers.toString());
    convertView.setTag(holder);

    Log.i("Item:", "" + numbers.get(position));
    holder.numbers.setText(numbers.get(position));


    return convertView;
}

public final class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView numbers;
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class ConversationThreads extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListView listview;
CardListviewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversation_threads);
    this.listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.conversationListview);
    populateConversations();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_conversation_threads, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void populateConversations()
{
    Log.d("Populate", "Populating...");

    //Array of Strings returned -- Target Data

    ArrayList<String> numbers = TSMS.getConversationNumbers(getApplicationContext());
    adapter = new CardListviewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),numbers);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

Listview.xml Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".CThreads"
android:id="@+id/conversationThreadLayout">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/conversationListview" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

conversation.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/numbertitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/lastmessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numbertitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit: Fixed Listview ID error, however result is unchanged.**
**Edit2: Problem was white background listview, and white text.

          Answer credit to @N1to, provided in comments.**

Comment: your listview reference is **R.id.conversationListview**.
Also, initialize your ArrayList object in onCreate

Comment: Thanks for that @m0rpheu5, however the data, is still not being shown in the listview items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in code:

```
this.listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Listview);
```

Where in your XML your id is different:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/conversationListview" />
```

Also, move it to your `activity_conversation_threads.xml`, it doesn't need separate layout.

---

Add to class `ConversationThreads:

```
private ArrayList<String> numbers;
private CardListviewAdapter adapter;
```

And then change your method to:

```
private void populateConversations()
{
    Log.d("Populate", "Populating...");

    //Array of Strings returned -- Target Data

    numbers = TSMS.getConversationNumbers(getApplicationContext());

    Log.d("ArrayList size", String.valueOf(numbers.size()); // check if it returns non zero

    adapter = new CardListviewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),numbers);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

---

Code for adapter

```
public class CardListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> numbers;


    public CardListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> numbers) {

        this.context = context;
        this.numbers = numbers;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return numbers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.conversation, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rowView);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        holder.numbers.setText(numbers.get(position));

        return rowView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        private final TextView numbers;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            this.numbers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.numbertitle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've adjusted the mistake with the ListView ID, and have checked the arraylist size, (it is the correct size), and the contents (also correct). However text is still not rendered. Thanks for the listview fix.

Comment: Try my adapter and tell results.

Comment: I've tried the adapter you provided, unfortunately no change in results.

Comment: So it is in memory, but it doesn't display. Did you try using different background, font color etc. to be sure that you don't have situation "white text on white background" ?

Comment: My God.... I can't believe I didn't think about white text on white background, yep that was the problem, thanks very much @N1to :)